# Kotlin data class with use-site target annotation on type and type parameter

Tags: kotlin, annotations, data-class

I'm looking for a way to write a Kotlin data class that compiles the annotations to the same bytecode as the following Java class:

```java
public class Pet {

    private List<String> names;

    public @NonNull List<@NonNull String> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    // constructor, setter, etc. omitted
}
```

I tried to write the following data class and expected it to put the annotations on the getter's return type and return type parameter:

```kotlin
data class Pet(val names: @get:NonNull List<@get:NonNull String>)
```

But for each of the annotations I get two compile errors:

- This annotation is not applicable to target 'undefined target' and use site target '@get'
- This annotation is not applicable to target 'type usage' and use site target '@get'

The NonNull annotation is from the Java library [microprofile-graphql-api](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-graphql/blob/master/server/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/graphql/NonNull.java#L66-L70):

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Documented
public @interface NonNull {
}
```

I run into the same problem when I try to set the annotations on the field:

```kotlin
data class Pet(val names: @field:NonNull List<@field:NonNull String>)
```

If I remove the use-site targets, then it will compile but it will only compile the annotations into `@kotlin.Metadata` where they are not visible to a Java library that is not aware of Kotlin.

Is there a way to get the annotations on the type and type parameter of a getter method or field?

---

**Update**

The getNames() method in the Java snippet above compiles to

```
  public getNames()Ljava/util/List;
  @Lorg/eclipse/microprofile/graphql/NonNull;()
  @Lorg/eclipse/microprofile/graphql/NonNull;() : METHOD_RETURN, null
  @Lorg/eclipse/microprofile/graphql/NonNull;() : METHOD_RETURN, 0;
```

The first annotation is on the method, the second on the method return type (List) and the third on the method return type parameter (String). I'm looking for a solution that results in bytecode with at least the second and third annotations.

The proposed solutions so far and what they compile to

1.

```
data class Pet(@NonNull val names: List<@NonNull String>)
```

```
  public getNames()Ljava/util/List;
```

This solution does not contain any annotations on the getter method at all in the bytecode. The annotations are only compiled into @kotlin.Metadata where they are not visible to a Java library that is not aware of Kotlin.

2.

```
data class Pet(@get:NonNull val names: List<@NonNull String>)
```

```
  public final getNames()Ljava/util/List;
  @Lorg/eclipse/microprofile/graphql/NonNull;()
```

This solution only results in an annotation on the method, but not on the method return type or return type parameter.

Comment: `String` in Kotlin is already non nullable, `String?` is nullable. What are you trying to do this?

Comment: Doesn't the second-to-last sentence explain that? @cutiko

Comment: I'm using a java library that creates a GraphQL schema from code, but unfortunately is not aware of Kotlin and its non-nullable types.

Answer (score 0):

For the type parameter, you shouldn't use a use-site target at all. There's no use-site target keyword for generic types, I assume because there's no possible ambiguity about what it's targeting at that location.

For the property, you're placing the annotation in the wrong spot. It goes before `val`. And in this case, you don't need to specify `@get`, since this particular annotation doesn't support targeting method parameters, and properties [have higher priority than fields when annotating them](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets). You would only need to put `@field:` if you needed to specifically target the field itself.

So, all you need is:

```
data class Pet(@NonNull val names: List<@NonNull String>)
```

but you could use this for better clarity:

```
data class Pet(@get:NonNull val names: List<@NonNull String>)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first solution will only compile the annotations into @kotlin.Metadata where they are not visible to a Java library that is not aware of Kotlin. And the second solution will compile the annotation onto the getter method, but not its return type or type parameter.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference between an annotation being on a getter method and being on its return type. For the other issues, I'm not sure if it can be resolved. I don't know enough about how Java and Kotlin interact under the hood with annotations.

Comment: I updated the question to show the differences between both of your solutions and the Java code.